# Margin Remain on conteiner

Tags: css, image, margins

I would like to know a way to not leave left overs margin right, in other words, I would like to fill out the entire container with images, but i need make a space between the images.
I am using `margin-right`, ie, the problem is there.
There's  another way to do this?

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code ? Or make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? And can you explain a little more what do you want to do ?

Comment: I got 4x3 images, but i need fill up the entire content, making spaces between the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following css style, to remove right margin from every 4th element:

```
#container img:nth-child(4n+4) {  
    margin-right: none;
}
```

Comment: I didnt know this code "nth-child(4n+4)", but is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the same as Marcins awnser though it will still work in browsers who does not support the CSS3 nth-child selector.

Put a class on the last elements and remove the right border from that class

```
.you_class {  
    margin-right: none;
}
```

This should make it work in older browsers as well

Alternatively, if you have 4 x 3 seperate images.

give them a class or throw them in a container and just style directly on the images.

Either give them a colored border if you want to keep the blue border or just give them some margin to make some space between them

Comment: I cannot put a class to this 3 images on right, because that is generate by a wordpress plugin, each <li> separately. :/ If i put in one, will be to all.

Comment: Hmm, so assuming that each row of images of li enclosed ina ul, you can use the :last-child selector to target the back most li and just style the crap out of it!